# make picture of pixeldata in xml-file

Tags: xml, image, pixel, data-extraction

I use a microscope taking images of particles. I get data out in an xml-file that contain information( see extract of a file) and I wonder if the entry pixel can be used to get the picture that has been taken of the particle. I'm confused if it is pixel data, because some entries also have letters. If it is possible, how can it be done?

`<particledata FileVersion="1.0"> <data measurement="2022-09-26 13:31:34.4610 0228 Q" product="EQPT" filter="<<DIAMETER_EQPC >= 1E-5>> AND <<DIAMETER_EQPC <= 0.0002>>"/> <particle frame="181" EQPC="5.92777219475097e-05" FERET_MAX="6.16502327208423e-05" FERET_MIN="5.96099987626077e-05" FERET_MEAN="6.09342368979882e-05" SPHERICITY="0.947197455424963" ASPECT_RATIO="0.966906305650574" CONVEXITY="0.956224350205198"> <image width="30" height="30" pixel="0E0000000100090001000B00070002001000060003001200050004001400040005001600030006001800020007001A00020008001A00010009001C0001000A001C0000000B001D0000000C001D0000000D001E0000000E001E0000000F001E00000010001E00000011001E00000012001D00010013001C00010014001C00010015001C00020016001A00020017001A0003001800180004001900160005001A00140006001B00110008001C000E000A001D000900"/> </particle> <particle frame="439" EQPC="1.75112776854003e-05" FERET_MAX="2.70261182554826e-05" FERET_MIN="1.98699995875359e-05" FERET_MEAN="2.33606593187573e-05" SPHERICITY="0.539453245456778" ASPECT_RATIO="0.735214706000371" CONVEXITY="0.635416666666667"> <image width="12" height="10" pixel="0800000001000500010005000500020005000100010003000100020003000100030009000100040004000600040005000100050005000700050004000000060004000800060002000100070002000800070004000200080001000800080002000B0008000100080009000100"/> </particle>`

Comment: Please don't forget to acknowledge @ardget's answer and efforts to assist you.

Answer (score 1):

Though it's an unknown data format, but it seems, a series of integer coordinates (x,y) in 16bit [hexadecimal format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) are stored sequentially in [little endian byte-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Therefore, by repeating (1) fetch 4 hexadecimal digits and (2) parse them as a little-endian integer as follows, you may be able to obtain all the plot-points required to draw a graph.

```
0E 00  -> 0x000e = 14  x0
00 00  -> 0x0000 = 0   y0
01 00  -> 0x0001 = 1   x1 
09 00  -> 0x0009 = 9   y1
:
```

#### Appendix: Attempt to parse it programmatically.

If javascript is used, the `pixel` data could be parsed as follows.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const pixelsData = document.getElementById('pixelsData');
let backup = pixelsData.value;

function parsePixels(pixels) {

    let points = [];
    let matches = String(pixels).matchAll(/([0-9A-F]{2})([0-9A-F]{2})([0-9A-F]{2})([0-9A-F]{2})/g);
    let m;
    while(!(m = matches.next()).done) {
        const x = parseInt(m.value[2] + m.value[1], 16);
        const y = parseInt(m.value[4] + m.value[3], 16);
        points.push([x, y]);
    }
    return points;
}
function parseIt() {
        
    let rawCoordinates = pixelsData.value;

    let points = parsePixels(rawCoordinates); // [ [x,y], ...]
    if (points.length < 1) return;

    backup = rawCoordinates;
    pixelsData.value = points.map(xy => xy.join("\t")).join("\n");

    // Plot points on the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.scale(5, 5);
    points.forEach(xy => { ctx.fillRect(xy[0], xy[1], 1, 1); });
    ctx.resetTransform();
}
function resetIt() {
    pixelsData.value = backup;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

```css
canvas {  border: solid silver 1px;}
button {  margin: 8px 0px 8px 0px;}
textarea {  width: 320px;  height: 240px;}
```

```html
<canvas width="160" height="160"></canvas><br/>
<button onclick="parseIt()">Parse</button> <button onclick="resetIt()">Reset</button> <br/>
<textarea id="pixelsData" >0E0000000100090001000B00070002001000060003001200050004001400040005001600030006001800020007001A00020008001A00010009001C0001000A001C0000000B001D0000000C001D0000000D001E0000000E001E0000000F001E00000010001E00000011001E00000012001D00010013001C00010014001C00010015001C00020016001A00020017001A0003001800180004001900160005001A00140006001B00110008001C000E000A001D000900</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Full kudos to @ardget for sleuthing the format of the pixel data! I felt like doing a Python version as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
from PIL import Image
from struct import unpack
from binascii import unhexlify

xml = """<particledata FileVersion="1.0"> <data measurement="2022-09-26 13:31:34.4610 0228 Q" product="EQPT" filter="<<DIAMETER_EQPC >= 1E-5>> AND <<DIAMETER_EQPC <= 0.0002>>"/> <particle frame="181" EQPC="5.92777219475097e-05" FERET_MAX="6.16502327208423e-05" FERET_MIN="5.96099987626077e-05" FERET_MEAN="6.09342368979882e-05" SPHERICITY="0.947197455424963" ASPECT_RATIO="0.966906305650574" CONVEXITY="0.956224350205198"> <image width="30" height="30" pixel="0E0000000100090001000B00070002001000060003001200050004001400040005001600030006001800020007001A00020008001A00010009001C0001000A001C0000000B001D0000000C001D0000000D001E0000000E001E0000000F001E00000010001E00000011001E00000012001D00010013001C00010014001C00010015001C00020016001A00020017001A0003001800180004001900160005001A00140006001B00110008001C000E000A001D000900"/> </particle> <particle frame="439" EQPC="1.75112776854003e-05" FERET_MAX="2.70261182554826e-05" FERET_MIN="1.98699995875359e-05" FERET_MEAN="2.33606593187573e-05" SPHERICITY="0.539453245456778" ASPECT_RATIO="0.735214706000371" CONVEXITY="0.635416666666667"> <image width="12" height="10" pixel="0800000001000500010005000500020005000100010003000100020003000100030009000100040004000600040005000100050005000700050004000000060004000800060002000100070002000800070004000200080001000800080002000B0008000100080009000100"/> </particle>""" 

seq = 0
# Iterate over all <image width=/height=/pixel=> occurrences in xml string
for match in re.finditer('<image width="(\d+)" height="(\d+)" pixel="([0-9A-F]+)"', xml):
    # Extract width, height and pixels
    width, height, pixel = match.groups()
    filename = f'extracted-{seq}.png'
    print(f'Image width: {width}, height: {height} -> {filename}')
    # Make a new, empty, black image the correct size
    im = Image.new('L', (int(width)+1,int(height)+1))

    # Unpack the hideous hex into groups of 4 hexdigits, each a short
    shorts = [pixel[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(pixel), 4)]
    # print('DEBUG: ', shorts)
    # Convert little-endian short hex string things into integers
    px = [unpack('<H', unhexlify(short))[0] for short in shorts]
    # print('DEBUG: ',px)

    # Put the pixels in the image with white colour - slowly but there are only a few
    for i in range(0, len(px), 2):
        x, y = px[i], px[i+1]
        im.putpixel((x,y), 255)
        # print(f'DEBUG: x={x}, y={y}')

    # Save the image 
    im.save(filename)
    seq += 1
```

Which produces two PNGs as follows:

```
-rw-r--r--@    1 mark  staff     1376 22 Nov 13:01 extracted-0.png
-rw-r--r--@    1 mark  staff      861 22 Nov 13:01 extracted-1.png
```

Slightly scaled up for added visibility:

[image] [image]

---

I note that there are pixel positions of 0 and 30 in the data, giving a range of 31 pixels, however the image size is given as 30. There is some inconsistency in the input data, or our understanding of it at least. I made the image 1 pixel taller and wider than its dimensions suggest.